# Using Python and YOLOv8 for simple bounding box creation. Program won't stop and can't be aborted

Tags: python, loops, exit, yolo

I wrote (or acuatlly mainly coppied) the following code. I am a rookie programmer and want to try out computer vision. When I execute this program , it works just fine, but i am unable to stop the code from running once it has generated the required image with bounding boxes. I thought writing stuff like exit() or q or quit in the VSCode terminal would abort the program, but so far i needed to restart VS Code in order to end the programm.

I am fully aware that there is probably an answer on the internet. I did my best to find it, but I just could not understand what I need to look for. Help would be so much aprechiated.

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import cv2
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")


# display the label of the detected object
def box_label(image, box, label='', color=(128, 128, 128), txt_color=(255, 255, 255)):
  lw = max(round(sum(image.shape) / 2 * 0.003), 2)
  p1, p2 = (int(box[0]), int(box[1])), (int(box[2]), int(box[3]))
  cv2.rectangle(image, p1, p2, color, thickness=lw, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
  if label:
    tf = max(lw - 1, 1)  # font thickness
    w, h = cv2.getTextSize(label, 0, fontScale=lw / 3, thickness=tf)[0]  # text width, height
    outside = p1[1] - h >= 3
    p2 = p1[0] + w, p1[1] - h - 3 if outside else p1[1] + h + 3
    cv2.rectangle(image, p1, p2, color, -1, cv2.LINE_AA)  # filled
    cv2.putText(image,
                label, (p1[0], p1[1] - 2 if outside else p1[1] + h + 2),
                0,
                lw / 3,
                txt_color,
                thickness=tf,
                lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
# Plot Bounding Boxes    
def plot_bboxes(image, boxes, labels=[], colors=[], score=True, conf=None):
  #Define COCO Labels
  if labels == []:
    labels = {0: u'__background__', 1: u'person', 2: u'bicycle',3: u'car', 4: u'motorcycle', 5: u'airplane', 6: u'bus', 7: u'train', 8: u'truck', 9: u'boat', 10: u'traffic light', 11: u'fire hydrant', 12: u'stop sign', 13: u'parking meter', 14: u'bench', 15: u'bird', 16: u'cat', 17: u'dog', 18: u'horse', 19: u'sheep', 20: u'cow', 21: u'elephant', 22: u'bear', 23: u'zebra', 24: u'giraffe', 25: u'backpack', 26: u'umbrella', 27: u'handbag', 28: u'tie', 29: u'suitcase', 30: u'frisbee', 31: u'skis', 32: u'snowboard', 33: u'sports ball', 34: u'kite', 35: u'baseball bat', 36: u'baseball glove', 37: u'skateboard', 38: u'surfboard', 39: u'tennis racket', 40: u'bottle', 41: u'wine glass', 42: u'cup', 43: u'fork', 44: u'knife', 45: u'spoon', 46: u'bowl', 47: u'banana', 48: u'apple', 49: u'sandwich', 50: u'orange', 51: u'broccoli', 52: u'carrot', 53: u'hot dog', 54: u'pizza', 55: u'donut', 56: u'cake', 57: u'chair', 58: u'couch', 59: u'potted plant', 60: u'bed', 61: u'dining table', 62: u'toilet', 63: u'tv', 64: u'laptop', 65: u'mouse', 66: u'remote', 67: u'keyboard', 68: u'cell phone', 69: u'microwave', 70: u'oven', 71: u'toaster', 72: u'sink', 73: u'refrigerator', 74: u'book', 75: u'clock', 76: u'vase', 77: u'scissors', 78: u'teddy bear', 79: u'hair drier', 80: u'toothbrush'}
  #Define colors
  if colors == []:
    #colors = [(6, 112, 83), (253, 246, 160), (40, 132, 70), (205, 97, 162), (149, 196, 30), (106, 19, 161), (127, 175, 225), (115, 133, 176), (83, 156, 8), (182, 29, 77), (180, 11, 251), (31, 12, 123), (23, 6, 115), (167, 34, 31), (176, 216, 69), (110, 229, 222), (72, 183, 159), (90, 168, 209), (195, 4, 209), (135, 236, 21), (62, 209, 199), (87, 1, 70), (75, 40, 168), (121, 90, 126), (11, 86, 86), (40, 218, 53), (234, 76, 20), (129, 174, 192), (13, 18, 254), (45, 183, 149), (77, 234, 120), (182, 83, 207), (172, 138, 252), (201, 7, 159), (147, 240, 17), (134, 19, 233), (202, 61, 206), (177, 253, 26), (10, 139, 17), (130, 148, 106), (174, 197, 128), (106, 59, 168), (124, 180, 83), (78, 169, 4), (26, 79, 176), (185, 149, 150), (165, 253, 206), (220, 87, 0), (72, 22, 226), (64, 174, 4), (245, 131, 96), (35, 217, 142), (89, 86, 32), (80, 56, 196), (222, 136, 159), (145, 6, 219), (143, 132, 162), (175, 97, 221), (72, 3, 79), (196, 184, 237), (18, 210, 116), (8, 185, 81), (99, 181, 254), (9, 127, 123), (140, 94, 215), (39, 229, 121), (230, 51, 96), (84, 225, 33), (218, 202, 139), (129, 223, 182), (167, 46, 157), (15, 252, 5), (128, 103, 203), (197, 223, 199), (19, 238, 181), (64, 142, 167), (12, 203, 242), (69, 21, 41), (177, 184, 2), (35, 97, 56), (241, 22, 161)]
    colors = [(89, 161, 197),(67, 161, 255),(19, 222, 24),(186, 55, 2),(167, 146, 11),(190, 76, 98),(130, 172, 179),(115, 209, 128),(204, 79, 135),(136, 126, 185),(209, 213, 45),(44, 52, 10),(101, 158, 121),(179, 124, 12),(25, 33, 189),(45, 115, 11),(73, 197, 184),(62, 225, 221),(32, 46, 52),(20, 165, 16),(54, 15, 57),(12, 150, 9),(10, 46, 99),(94, 89, 46),(48, 37, 106),(42, 10, 96),(7, 164, 128),(98, 213, 120),(40, 5, 219),(54, 25, 150),(251, 74, 172),(0, 236, 196),(21, 104, 190),(226, 74, 232),(120, 67, 25),(191, 106, 197),(8, 15, 134),(21, 2, 1),(142, 63, 109),(133, 148, 146),(187, 77, 253),(155, 22, 122),(218, 130, 77),(164, 102, 79),(43, 152, 125),(185, 124, 151),(95, 159, 238),(128, 89, 85),(228, 6, 60),(6, 41, 210),(11, 1, 133),(30, 96, 58),(230, 136, 109),(126, 45, 174),(164, 63, 165),(32, 111, 29),(232, 40, 70),(55, 31, 198),(148, 211, 129),(10, 186, 211),(181, 201, 94),(55, 35, 92),(129, 140, 233),(70, 250, 116),(61, 209, 152),(216, 21, 138),(100, 0, 176),(3, 42, 70),(151, 13, 44),(216, 102, 88),(125, 216, 93),(171, 236, 47),(253, 127, 103),(205, 137, 244),(193, 137, 224),(36, 152, 214),(17, 50, 238),(154, 165, 67),(114, 129, 60),(119, 24, 48),(73, 8, 110)]
  
  #plot each boxes
  for box in boxes:
    #add score in label if score=True
    if score :
      label = labels[int(box[-1])+1] + " " + str(round(100 * float(box[-2]),1)) + "%"
    else :
      label = labels[int(box[-1])+1]
    #filter every box under conf threshold if conf threshold setted
    if conf :
      if box[-2] > conf:
        color = colors[int(box[-1])]
        box_label(image, box, label, color)
    else:
      color = colors[int(box[-1])]
      box_label(image, box, label, color)

  #show image
  image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

  try:
    import google.colab
    IN_COLAB = True
  except:
    IN_COLAB = False

  if IN_COLAB:
    cv2_imshow(image) #if used in Colab
  else :
    # cv2.imshow(image) #if used in Python
    cv2.imshow('Test Image', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
      
# Download and display image from URL
response = requests.get("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600880292203-757bb62b4baf?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80")
#response = requests.get("https://jooinn.com/images/group-of-people-having-fun-together-under-the-sun-2.jpg")

image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
image = np.asarray(image)
results = model.predict(image)

plot_bboxes(image, results[0].boxes.data, score=False)
```

I was expecting that it would be somehow possible to stop the program from running, using exit() or quit or q, but it did not. I would think it would be ideal if the program stopped being executed once the window with the bounding boxes is closed. I have no idea how to do that.